# Layout of Flow launched from Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, visual-workflow, field-service-lightning

I configured a resource action in the "Dispatcher Console UI" of Field Service Admin; the action is of type Visualforce and the latter starts a flow approximately like this:

```html
<apex:page standardController="ServiceResource" lightningStylesheets="true">
<div>
    <flow:interview name="FSL_Schedule_a_Placeholder" buttonLocation="bottom">
        <apex:param name="PV_Service_Recource_ID" value="{!ServiceResource}"/>
    </flow:interview>
</div>
</apex:page>
```

This has all the prettiness of a flow started from Visualforce. As an example screen:

[image]

Just some of the unsightly details:

- Unnecessary scroll bars
- Lots of white space due to a two column layout with the right column left blank (and the footer button being positioned on the right side of the left column, although not being aligned with anything)
- Error messages with arbitrary line breaks and repetitions, assumably a gift from VF

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_flows_adding.htm) does not lose a word about the layout problems. Somehow I couldn't find anything helpful on Stack Exchange neither. What have I missed?

Just in case there are indeed no remedies - maybe Flows should rather not being launched from resource actions in the "Dispatcher Console UI" via VF? Alternatives?