# Record type using global picklist shows "bad value for restricted picklist error" twice

Tags: record-type, global-picklist, lightning-console

I have a record type using global picklist values. If any value is deactivated from the global picklist, it gets removed from the record type as well, which is correct; but it shows the "bad value for restricted picklist field" error twice on the standard page layout in lightning console. In classic it's working as expected and showing the error just once. I am not sure why this is happening in lightning. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000320321&type=1 Does this answer your question??

Comment: Unnecessary repetitions of field validation errors can be observed in other contexts as well, e.g. see my screenshot [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/370111/layout-of-flow-launched-from-visualforce) for a Flow.